# I have Unix scripting question

Tags: shell, text-processing

Input----

```
System:root,bin,user,saaa
```

Displayed output----

```
System,root
System,bin
System,user
System,says
```

How to get this output??

Comment: please explain what you want more detailed, I didn-t understand what you want to display or from what ....if it is only display formed you can work with sed or awk to filter output & make substitutions.

Comment: Is `System` a fixed string? Or may it be anything? Is the first column in your desired output intended to be anything word before `:`? Is it correct to state that you trying to repeat the word that sits before `:` on each output line, followed by just one of the words separated by commas in your input? Are those always comma-separated?

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange, maybe you could show us something you tried ? We are here to help, we like helping people, but some effort is required. Do you have a preferred program you would like to use ?

Comment: Which shell? bash or something else?

Comment: How do you map from `saaa` to `says`? If it's a typo please fix it.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend that you use `perl`, but since you specified shell scripting...

Step 1: split your line into two parts, based on the `:` character.  Use the `cut` command or the `${parameter#word}` and `${parameter%word}` constructs.

Step 2: split the second part of your line into multiple parts, based on the `,` character.  Use the `awk` command -- it should tell you how many pieces you will have (I'm not an `awk` expert, so I'm not sure that this will work the way I envision it.)

Step 3: cycle through the various parts you get from Step 2, attach them to the first part from Step 1, and print.

Answer (score 0):

If we can assume that your input lines contain exactly one colon (`:`), that no comma (`,`) may appear before the colon and that neither commas nor colons may be part of the extracted substrings (not even escaped), then a simple `awk` script may be enough:

```sh
$ printf '%s\n' 'System:one,two,three' |
    awk -v FS=':|,' '{ for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) { print $1","$i } }'
```

Output:

```
System,one
System,two
System,three
```

The field separator `FS` is an extended regular expression that will split on every character that is `:` or `,`.

---

If, instead, you want to pick everything up to the first colon (possibly including commas) as the first output field and split the remainder of any input line at any comma (assuming that no comma is intended to be preserved as part of any of the substrings (not even escaped)), you can resort to shell features, as suggested in [hymie's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/517642/315749):

```sh
$ printf '%s\n' 'System:one,two,three' |
    while IFS= read -r rem; do      # IFS= to preserve blank characters
      first=${rem%%:*}              # Remove from the first ':' on
      rem=${rem#"$first"}           # Remove first from the beginning of rem
      rem=${rem#:}                  # Strip the remaining ':' at rem's beginning
      while test "$rem"; do         # Exit when rem is empty
          second=${rem%%,*}         # Remove from the first ',' on
          rem=${rem#"$second"}      # Remove second from the beginning of rem
          rem=${rem#,}              # Strip the remaining ',' at rem's beginning
          printf '%s\n' "$first,$second"
      done
    done
```

Just make sure you understand the [caveats of using shell loops to process text](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/315749).

Alternatively, with GNU `sed`:

```sh
$ printf '%s\n' 'System:one,two,three' |
sed -n '
  :l1
    s/^[^:]*:\n//g;
    t l2;
  s/^\([^:]\{1,\}\):\([^,\n]\{1,\}\)*,\{0,1\}\(.*\)$/\1:\3\n\1,\2/;
    t l1;
  q;
  :l2 p;
'
```

Here, branching (`t`) to a label (`l1`) is used to process each line of input with a loop. One at a time, the substrings between the first `:` and the first following `,` are appended as new lines to the pattern space, concatenated after the substring that comes before the first `:`. When there is no further substring to extract, what remains of the original string is removed, the pattern space is printed and the program exits.

(With GNU `sed` version >= 4.6 you can look at what is happening, step by step, by invoking it with the `--debug` option).

Note that the use of `\n` inside bracket expressions to match (here, negate a match) a `<newline>` character is non-standard: POSIX states that `<backslash>` shall lose any special meaning in that context.